# Basic thread question

Tags: c#, multithreading

If i have a class

```
public Class foo
{
    public foo()
    {
        myclass = new myclass(param)
        myclass.initiateState();
        val = myclass.getValues();
    }
}
```

`Class.initiateState()` is a lengthy process which is running in my GUI constructor which I wanted to start running with a thread, however the next line goes to the same class to get some data back, yet if I run the first line in a new thread then this gets executed before it can finish.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, you should not load data anyway in the GUI constractor, GUI should be loaded and displayed quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a `BackgroundWorker`.

Inside the `DoWork` event method, add the `myClass.initiateState()` call. Inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` event method, call `myClass.getValues();`

This will cause `initiateState` to run on a background thread, and when finished will fire `getValues` on the GUI thread.

Also, note that in C# it's normal to start method names with an uppercase letter, compared to Java. So the methods should have the names `InitiateState` and `GetValues` :)

Comment: I think creating `BackgroundWorker` is syntax overhead if you don't need cancellation and progress notification.

Comment: @Andrey - It might be a bit longer, but it is very easy to read for others, and it's not that much longer anyway. And if he needs progress notification later on (he said it was a lengthy task) it will be easy to extend his existing work to implement those changes.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to do:

```
public Class foo
{
    public foo()
    {
        myclass = new myclass(param)
        new Action( () => myclass.initiateState() ).BeginInvoke(initiateStateFinished, null)
    }

   private void initiateStateFinished(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
      val = myclass.getValues();
      //other actions
   }
}
```

or even shorter

```
    public foo()
    {
        myclass = new myclass(param)
        new Action( () => myclass.initiateState() )
           .BeginInvoke(_ => val = myclass.getValues(), null)
    }
```

Comment: I havn't used Action's much before, so I have a question here. Will the initiateStateFinished method be called on the main GUI thread or on a background thread?

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen on background one

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to execute BOTH

```
    myclass.initiateState();
    val = myclass.getValues();
```

in a new thread (with the val being a return value)?

You can do that easily using .NET 4.0 `Tasks`, as such:

```
        var someBackgroundTask = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<*return type of GetValue()*>(() =>
            {
                myclass.initiateState();
                return myclass.getValue();
            });
        someBackgroundTask.Start();
```

and later use `someBackgroundTask.Result` to get the, well, result. The only problem you'll have is you'll need to wait (or check at key points) to see if the `Task` has finished. You can use `someBackgroundTask.IsCompleted` to check if it's still working or `someBackgroundTask.Wait()` to wait for it to finish.

EDIT: Than again, the suggestions above are probably better. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the example given it seems that the whole `foo` class should be ran in a separate thread. For the sake of being applicable to other circumstances I will assume there is something else in `foo` which shouldn't be run as a different thread.

---

First create a DoWork method in `foo`:

```
private void DoWork() {
    myclass = new myclass(param);
    myclass.initiateState();
    val = myclass.getValues();
}
```

Then change the constructor to run that as a thread:

```
public foo() {
   Thread workerThread = new Thread(this.DoWork);
   /* ... do other stuff ... */      
}
```

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4.aspx

Comment: This might cause some issue if `val` is used by the GUI thread also, but that is not specified by the OP. Thought I would just mention it ;)